# Processing.org applet out of IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, applet, processing, appletviewer

I merged my code from Processing.org into IDEA some time ago as it was just more comfortable to develop. Now I need to export the code to an applet. I already set up the configuration for that task, but it doesn't run with the appletviewer (it just closes after execution without showing anything). Do I need a jar-file? Is there a way to generate this in IDEA automatically?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I moved all the code back to Processing.org. It took some time, but at least it works now as an applet.

Comment: This is capitulation, not a solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Project Structure | Artifacts](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/artifacts.html).

Comment: Thanks! Build the jar, but still not running.

patrick$ appletviewer -debug App.jar 
Initializing jdb ...
> run
run sun.applet.Main Tweeteroids.jar
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
> 
VM Started: 
The application exited

Comment: I guess there is some problem with the app itself or with the packaging, not with IDEA.

Comment: appletviewer expects an html file and scans it for OBJECT, EMBED and APPLET tags. You can't feed it a jar. That would fail for your processing generated applet as well.